# Keep first document version and last "X" number of versions

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning

We are looking at our document library settings and wondering if it is possible to have the following for versioning:

1. Always keep the first version of a document uploaded
2. If we set versioning @ the library level, keep that first version and the version count set there after

So, if we create a document and upload 10 months ago, we want that version since it's a benchmark on where the document started from...basically where it began.  Then, if we turn on versioning 14 months later to say 3 major versions, we'll want the first version created 10 months ago as well as the last 3 major versions uploaded for that document.

Seems like once we turn versioning on, it's looking at revision count and that's it, but wanted to make 100% sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It goes based off of just major versions, (optionally) drafts of major versions and only starts from the point where you turn on versioning. If you have been editing a document all along and then turn on versioning, the first version to be saved is the one that was published when versioning was turned on.

If you want something other than that, you'll have to write custom code or use a workflow (which would be a bit obnoxious since there would be quite a few documents each with permanent workflows)

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable versioning, every changes create a new version. You can decide version numbering. And decide Major/Minor versions.

You can use Version History to restore or download previous version of the document.

You can enable content approval. In this case only Published and Approved documents will gets added to the versions as opposed to every minor version getting into.